# SQL Server Report Builder - Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

My condition is that industry who has paying highest time amount and total receivable amount of that industry

[image: 1]

My expected result is ABC industry is highest number of count and total receive amount for that is 3584

I am trying find SSRS expression for above query but I couldn't. please help me

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be better to do this in your dataset query, something like this.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(IndustryType Varchar(3), Amount int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('ABC', 500),('XYZ', 304),('KLM', 683),('ABC', 529),('ERJ', 703),
    ('XYZ', 902),('ABC', 852),('KLM', 950),('ABC', 703),('ABC', 1000)

SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM(
        SELECT IndustryType, COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount 
            FROM @t
            GROUP BY IndustryType
    ) x 
    ORDER BY x.cnt DESC
```

This gives the following results

[image]

If you cannot do this for whatever reason, edit your question and show what the final output should look like.

Comment: Alan thanks for this solution but I want expression for stored procedure. Could you please provide me expression ?

Comment: As I said in the answer, if this does not help, EDIT your question and show what you expect the final output to look like in the report. I think this might be quite difficult to achieve as an expression, that's why I offered an alternative